# Why should the Community bot vote on suggested edits?

Tags: discussion

I just suggested an edited to this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88375/dynamic-regression-and-panel-models). For instance, the sentence "I was told that I should use an aroma with regressors" was clearly meant to say ARIMA rather than aroma (usually autocorrect on cell phones does stuff like that). So I suggested to correct this and to add the forecasting tag.

The Community bot immediately voted to reject this suggested edit. Now this got me wondering: why should the bot vote if it can't tell whether an edit is sensical or not?

Comment: The record of your first attempted edit is at http://stats.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/28751.  It shows the Community bot did indeed reject it.  As far as I can tell it was a legitimate edit (which I would have approved); I cannot see anything that should have triggered an automatic rejection.  Strange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have been through Community user rejecting suggested edits either.

It seems most of the rejection cases is because of editing conflicts. Maybe the OP had had the edit button activated the time you did the action.

See the following thread on Meta Stack Overflow for more information on this matter:

[How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284)

I will quote a relevant part of it:

> ....
> Sometimes the Community user approves or rejects my edit. What does that mean?
>
> The Community user will appear to approve or reject your edit when one of the following two cases apply:
> ...
> You submit a suggested edit at the same time as the original poster or a 2000+ rep user (20000+ in the case of tag wikis) or any moderator (in other words, anyone who has full edit privileges over the specific post). In that case, your suggested edit will be rejected by Community in favor of the fully privileged edit. Since the Community user does not provide a message when such an edit is rejected, it may appear as though the system has rejected your edit immediately, without warning. Don't worry! This has nothing to do with bans, or your profile being banned from suggesting edits. Just try submitting your edit again and it could make it to the review queue.
>
> In any case, suggested edits rejected by Community are not counted towards the suggested edit ban.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the [Community bot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) doesn't actually vote, it "owns" votes that cannot be otherwise attributed to a user.  I'm not sure what that would mean in this context.  However, I [don't see a record](https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/28753) that your edit was rejected.  @user603 and I both approved your edit, and it [seems to have been made](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88375/dynamic-regression-and-panel-models).

Comment: That's because I sent the edit a second time after receiving this:
Rejected 3 hours ago:
Community♦ reviewed this 3 hours ago: Reject

Comment: I don't see that in the [history](http://stats.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history).

Comment: And the same thing just happened again: Community♦ reviewed this 12 secs ago: Reject. Should I post a screen shot?

Comment: Could it be that the user himself made a change to the post after my edit suggestion could be reviewed such that the system automatically rejected the change?

Comment: I don't see a [record](http://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/88375/revisions) of the OP making an edit around that time. From @whuber's comment above, I guess some of these things are hidden from me, so maybe it happened anyway somehow. It is also possible for the OP to reject / accept suggested edits to their post, but that should show up in the history as well. It does seem rather strange.